# Map a property to a column generate it with .Map(t => t.MapKey("GroupId"))

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-relationship

I'm developing an Entity Framework Code First (v. 4.4.0.0) C# library with .Net Framework 4.0.

I'm trying to represent that a talk can have zero or one group.

With these two classes:

**Talk** class:

```
[DataContract]
public class Talk
{
    [DataMember]
    public int TalkId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int StarterUserId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int? RecipientUserId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int? RecipientGroupId { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateUtcStarted { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string DateStarted
    {
        get
        {
            return DateUtcStarted.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
        }
        set
        {
            DateUtcStarted = DateTime.Parse(value);
        }
    }

    public User StarterUser { get; set; }
    public User RecipientUser { get; set; }

    public virtual Group RecipientGroup { get; set; }
}
```

**TalkConfiguration** class:

```
class TalkConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Talk>
{
    public TalkConfiguration()
    {
        Property(t => t.RecipientGroupId).HasColumnName("GroupId");
        Property(t => t.StarterUserId).IsRequired();
        Property(t => t.RecipientUserId).IsOptional();
        Property(t => t.RecipientGroupId).IsOptional();
        Property(t => t.DateUtcStarted).IsRequired();

        Ignore(t => t.DateStarted);

        HasRequired(t => t.StarterUser).
            WithMany(u => u.TalksStarted).
            HasForeignKey(t => t.StarterUserId);
        HasOptional(t => t.RecipientUser).
            WithMany(u => u.InTalks).
            HasForeignKey(t => t.RecipientUserId);

        HasOptional(t => t.RecipientGroup).WithOptionalDependent(g => g.GroupTalk).Map(t => t.MapKey("GroupId"));
    }
}
```

I get this error message:

```
The scheme is invalid. Error 0019: Each property name in a type must be unique.
The property name is already defined.
```

If I remove the property:

```
public int? RecipientGroupId { get; set; }
```

It works.

How can I map `RecipientGroupId` to the database column `GroupId` generated here: `HasOptional(t => t.RecipientGroup).WithOptionalDependent(g => g.GroupTalk).Map(t => t.MapKey("GroupId"));`?